# copy files using listed in text file, how to copy files and with folders and it's subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I want to copy several files listed in `file.txt` file.txt` file contains the relative path:

```
web/main/src/web/login.txt
web/main/src/ht/pro.i
web/main/src/log/ss.p
```

When I run the following script:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "file.txt"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "\DestinationFolder"
```

I get the following output only:

```
output: DestinationFolder
login.txt
pro.i
ss.p
```

But I want following output:

```
web/main/src/web/login.txt
web/main/src/ht/pro.i
web/main/src/log/ss.p
```

or  #understanding purpose only

```
web/main/src/web/login.txt
            /ht/pro.i
            /log/ss.p
```

How can I achieve this?

How to copy with folders and it's subfolders.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: How to copy file include it's folders and subfolders.